# Signals don't work when outside MQTT script inserts data to database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-signals, django-3.0

I have django project and I have signals in model.py file. I created demo just to show what problem is

```
def func(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    
    try:
        if created:
           print("WORKED")
    except BaseException as e:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())


post_save.connect(func, sender=MyTable,
                  dispatch_uid="IDDD")
```

When I insert data from admin panel, everything is OK, it prints,however, when I use simple script which inserts to **MyTable** by using **psycopg**, signal does not work, but data is saved to the table.

Comment: A lot of queryset functions circumvent signals, especially updates *in bulk*. It is (often) not a good idea to use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I inserted data through api, everything worked.